# Distribution of mean*standard deviation of sample from gaussian

Tags: r

I'm trying to assess the feasibility of an instrumental variable in my project with a variable I havent seen before. The variable essentially is an interaction between the mean and standard deviation of a sample drawn from a gaussian, and im trying to see what this distribution might look like. Below is what im trying to do, any help is much appreciated.

Generate a set of 1000 individuals with a variable `x` following the gaussian distribution, draw 50 random samples of 5 individuals from this distribution with replacement, calculate the means and standard deviation of `x` for each sample, create an interaction variable named `y` which is calculated by multiplying the mean and standard deviation of `x` for each sample, plot the distribution of `y`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? The components of what you need: `rnorm()`, `sample(..., replace = TRUE)`, `mean()`, `sd()`, `hist()`.  Can you put the pieces together?

Comment: Maybe do that and try it yourself, first. If it doesn't work, you can come back for the answer I posted.

Comment: Thank you all so much! Sorry for not posting what I had tried so far, I am new to this forum and will make sure to do that next time

Answer (score 0):

**Beginners version**

There might be more efficient ways to code this, but this is easy to follow, I guess:

```
stat_pop <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)

N = 50
# As Ben suggested, we create a data.frame filled with NA values
samples <- data.frame(mean = rep(NA, N), sd = rep(NA, N))
# Now we use a loop to populate the data.frame
for(i in 1:N){
  # draw 5 samples from population (without replacement)
  # I assume you want to replace for each turn of taking 5
  # If you want to replace between drawing each of the 5,
  # I think it should be obvious how to adapt the following code
  smpl <- sample(stat_pop, size = 5, replace = FALSE)
  # the data.frame currently has two columns. In each row i, we put mean and sd
  samples[i, ] <- c(mean(smpl), sd(smpl))
}

# $ is used to get a certain column of the data.frame by the column name.
# Here, we create a new column y based on the existing two columns.
samples$y <- samples$mean * samples$sd

# plot a histogram
hist(samples$y)
```

Most functions here use positional arguments, i.e., you are not required to name every parameter. E.g., `rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)` is the same as `rnorm(1000, 0, 1)` and even the same as `rnorm(1000)`, since  `0` and `1` are the default values.

**Somewhat more efficient version**

In R, loops are very inefficient and, thus, ought to be avoided. In case of your question, it does not make any noticeable difference. However, for large data sets, performance should be kept in mind. The following might be a bit harder to follow:

```
stat_pop <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
N = 50
n = 5

# again, I set replace = FALSE here; if you meant to replace each individual
# (so the same individual can be drawn more than once in each "draw 5"),
# set replace = TRUE
# replicate repeats the "draw 5" action N times
smpls <- replicate(N, sample(stat_pop, n, replace = FALSE))
# we transform the output and turn it into a data.frame to make it
# more convenient to work with
samples <- data.frame(t(smpls))

samples$mean <- rowMeans(samples)
samples$sd <- apply(samples[, c(1:n)], 1, sd)
samples$y <- samples$mean * samples$sd
hist(samples$y)
```

**General note**

Usually, you should do some research on the problem before posting here. Then, you either find out how it works by yourself, or you can provide an example of what you tried. To this end, you can simply google each of the steps you outlined (e.g., google "generate random standard distribution R" in order to find out about the function `rnorm()`.
Run `?rnorm` to get help on the function in RStudio.

Comment: The question dictates that the draws are WITH replacement

Comment: You're probably right that building the data frame row-by-row is good enough for this problem, but it's a bad habit to get into (painfully efficient for larger problems)

Comment: @onyambu I was not sure what is to be replaced. You can draw 5 individuals in a row and replace each, or you can draw a group of 5 and replace the entire group before drawing a new group. I tried to explain in the comments and I named the arguments so it should be easily understandable and can be set as needed.

Comment: @BenBolker I just thought it an easy to follow example. Btw., sorry for giving an answer away so easily, I just saw you had a somewhat more educational approach...

Comment: *inefficient in previous comment

Comment: can improve slightly by doing `samples <- data.frame(mean = rep(NA, N), sd = rep(NA, N))` at the beginning,   then `samples[i, ] <- c(mean(smpl), sd(smpl))`